# vuetify v-list-item not recognizing named routes

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router, vuetifyjs3

I'm learning vue so this could be "school" error, I was searching for answers but lot's of them are couple years old.

I'm using vuetify  ^3.0.0

my route:

```
const routes = [
{
  path: '/requests',
  component: () => import('@/layouts/default/Request.vue'),
  children: [
    {
      path: '/new-request',
      name: 'new-request',
      component: () => import(/* "new-request" */ '@/views/requests/NewRequestView.vue'),
    }
  ]
}
]
```

my list:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    expand-on-hover
    rail
    permanent
  >
   <v-list density="compact" nav>
      <v-list-group value="Request">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-list-item
            v-bind="props"
            title="Requests"
            prepend-icon="mdi-newspaper-variant-outline"
          ></v-list-item>
        </template>
        <v-list-item
          link
          title="New Request"
          prepend-icon="mdi-newspaper-plus"
          exact
          to="/request/new-request"
          value="new-request"
        ></v-list-item>
       </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

currently when clicking on list element it's working like should, but it's not named route. so how to use in above example use named route, so I will type component name in "to"?

Comment: `:to="{ name: 'someName' }"` should do it.

Comment: yes it's works. I try many different way but not this one. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As tao suggested in his comment:

```html
<v-list-item :to="{ name: 'someName' }" />
```

...works.

Tried different options but not this one, which is the correct answer.